# LINQ how to add an order by to this statement?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ that I would like to also order by file creation date, how is this done?

```
taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles(Id + "*.xml")
 .Where(fi => !fi.Name.EndsWith("_update.xml", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
 .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
taskFiles = taskDirectory.GetFiles(Id + "*.xml")
 .Where(fi => !fi.Name.EndsWith("_update.xml", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
 .OrderBy(fi => fi.CreationTime)
 .ToArray();
```

**or**

```
var taskFiles = from taskFile in taskDirectory.GetFiles(Id + "*.xml")
                where !taskFile.Name.EndsWith("_update.xml", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                orderby taskFile.CreationTime
                select taskFile;
```